# Programming for Nokia 6700 classic (in Java)

Tags: java, java-me, nokia

Does anyone know any resources to start programming in Java for Nokia 6700 classic (not touch screen)? Thanks.

P. S. Here is an image of the phone I want to program for:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, apps for these kinds of phones can be made with [Java Micro Edition (Java ME)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/overview/getstarted/index.html), but I wouldn't count on it being a pleasant experience.

Comment: Looks less unpleasant than it used to be

Comment: @jdphenix: I don't doubt that, but I still wouldn't endeavour to try it out ;-)

Comment: Nvm, I know that might sound stupid, but I some how can't install it... I mean I followed a tutorial, launched installed. It said installation is complete. But I can't find the SDK. I only see Phone Emulators...

Comment: @Vik2015: I haven't used Java ME myself, so I don't know how it is supposed to be used. However, it's possible that the SDK mostly consists of Java libraries and doesn't contain any other programs than the emulator, and that you should just use some standard Java IDE (such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA) and build applications that target Java ME.

Comment: @Vik2015: I see from your profile that you are teaching yourself how to program (cool!) - so I would recommend that you stay away from Java ME and spend your time on more modern technologies (Java ME is old and used less and less, and knowing Java ME does not help much when you want to learn e.g. Android development). If you want to make apps, you could download the Android SDK (which is also based on Java) and use Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA to make apps that you can run in an emulator until you can buy an Android phone.

Comment: @AasmundEldhuset, well, that is probably a good idea :). I will try it out

Comment: @Vik2015: Good luck! :-) By the way, since Android (and Java ME) is just a set of libraries (extensions) to Java, you might want to learn regular Java first - it is easier to get started with.

Comment: I would recommend using Nokia Series 40 6th Edition SDK for the device since it would be the original designed for it, and would include all special APIs as well.